# How to get the Key Pressed in WinRT

Tags: c#, events, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I had used OnTextInput Event to get the Key Pressed by the end user in WPF/Silverlight, but in case of WinRT I dont have such events and I am struck with KeyDown Event.  Though the event returns the Key Pressed by the User, I am not able to differentiate the case (i.e, lower or upper case) as the event returns VirtualKey Enum.

Is there any possible workarounds?

Regards

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh868246.aspx

Comment: Try `TextChanged` event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of WinRT programmers have this problem, the event just isn't very discoverable.  Microsoft hasn't been consistent enough about naming this event.  It is KeyPress in Winforms, TextInput in WPF.  Yet another choice for WinRT, it is the [CharacterReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx) event.